# slideToggle reveals then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle

Currently trying to add a slideToggle function to my website

http://louislantos.com/
I want clicking the (+) text next to the heading in the tiles to reveal a description, which it does, but it almost immediately slides the content back into display: none; territory once again.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I've been googling this for the past 2 hours, and I feel myself getting nowhere. It's probably a very basic problem for someone a lot more skilled than I, so any help is appreciated. Perhaps a script conflict or something?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QNZMP/ Everything looks fine, for some reason the click event seems to be getting triggered twice, is there any other place where it is located?

Comment: Just a wild shot but perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the site has two jquery library loaded at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something else indeed is triggering that click event twice (one extra time). I couldnt find it, so i present you with this hack:

```
$("#reveal-416").unbind("click").click(function () { 
   $(".revealer-416").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

by far not ideal, but it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works a treat. Why is it not ideal? Because it's a hack? Or is there something more sinister at play?

Comment: because you shouldnt have to unbind click like that. you should know where its coming from and fix it in that place

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try changing it to toggle with slideup and slidedown as arguments?